# How can i stop app from restarting on crash and make crashes visible?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I am working on an app and using HUAWEI phone for testing, whenever a crash happen app gets restarted and logs become disappear. Is there any setting in developer option or some thing else that can let crash dialog appears and shows crash logs.

Answer (score 9):

I learnt this recently, hopefully it helps others out there.

Debug as you normally would, but once the crash and restart happens open up the Logcat tab.
In the Logcat window at the top you can then select your previous process.
It should be something like:

> com.myapp.app(1234)[DEAD]

That'll give you the logs before the restart.

Comment: I could have sworn there used to be a developer setting to not restart the app but can't find it now. This works instead!

Comment: Nope - Mine doesn't show previous process, only the new one that was created .

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [Uncaught Exception Handler](https://github.com/jampez77/UCE-Handler)

[image]
[image]

**Setup**

In your Project's build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       ...
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
}
```

In your Application's or Module's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.jampez77:UCE-Handler:uce_handler:1.4.3'
}
```

In your Application class:

- Initialize library using builder pattern.

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
     @Override 
     public void onCreate() { 
        ...
        // Initialize UCE_Handler Library
        new UCEHandler.Builder(this).build();
     } 
  }
  ```

Comment: This is one solution but i want to know why app keeps on restarting without crash dialog and when it restarts it remove previous logs that contains the errors

Answer (score 2):

You can run the app Debugger mode and keep a break point in the activity where the crash occurs and navigate by going to next line using F8 until you encounter the crash.

Comment: Basically it restarts app and wont show the lines where crash happens

Comment: You can then try navigating from the previous activity in the **Debugger mode** and use F8 to parse through the lines until you encounter the crash. If you still encounter the restarting of the app, try debugging the app in the emulator.