# Debugging app from the device without USB and WIFI

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

Since my app runs on the emulator and crashes on my device. I would like to see log report of my app directly from the device. So that it might lead to better way of debugging. But I have following problems

1. My device is connected to the PC via LAN.
2. My device doesn't have USB connection (no slave port).

I am using android studio as IDE. I have seen couple of examples which could be used if the device is connected to same wifi network like [Debugging over wifi network](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root) but this doesn't help.

There is an official documentation with wifi [official documentation for wifi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless) still it needs USB connection in step 3.

Does Android Studio provide any type of solution?

Comment: The method in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless) works fine for me. I can debug over Wi-Fi.

Comment: hello markus, Is there any way without `wifi and usb` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. You said you can't use USB and it's needed in the steps.

Comment: Connect the device to the host computer with a USB cable.

Comment: haha, yes I just saw that too .!

Comment: Can you connect your device to another PC with `ADB` installed? The config through USB only has to be done once after device reboot.

Comment: how can I connect ? Thats my question ? I dont have USB slave port in my device(I have only master port).It is not android  phone, its android telephone.

Comment: An "Uncaught Exception Handler" app was mentioned in [How can i stop app from restarting on crash and make crashes visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110011/how-can-i-stop-app-from-restarting-on-crash-and-make-crashes-visible). I haven't tried it myself yet, but apparently you would at least get the crash log from the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the crash reports from any android device you can use crashlytics..
This is very nice library which provides you very details logs of crash along with many other details like android device name, ram size, memory, orientation etc..

Good thing is that this crashlytics was different library previously, which is now part of **Firebase**  .
To get started you can know about crashlytics from   [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) you can follow the documentation from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android)

Comment: Never heard of this. I will give it a try now. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

if your app is firebase configured maybe you can use `DebugView` from firebase site.

Comment: First,,I shoud register in firebase. The answer by @Ichigo made me to did deep. Now I understood. Both are really helpful. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, firebase helps you get the crashlytics. The error message will be stated in the dashboard once the app crashes. This is a life saver but I found out that, we can simply connect the device to IDE without USB. Just the PC and your device should be connected via LAN

1. Using ADB tool. Run the `adb.exe` file as admin. Connect using tcp. Just address and Port is necessary.
2. You can simply debug from the IDE, In my case android studio.